# display csv in browser with charset utf-8, using php and headers

Tags: php, csv, pdf, cloud, charset

In a cloud-like web application I want to display files directly in browser, which works perfectly for .PDF and images using this code:

```
if (file_exists($serverfile)) {
    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type ($serverfile) . '; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $origname . '"');
    header('content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-length: ' . filesize($serverfile));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    readfile($serverfile);
    //... more unrelated code
    exit;
}
```

but I have scrumbled characters e.g. with German Umlauts, in case the file is a .CSV

I also set `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');` on top of the script.

What am I missing ?

Comment: My guess would be that the csv-files are not utf-8 encoded. On a Linux system you could check that in the shell with `file some-file.csv`. You could then transform the file using `iconv()` before sending it.

Comment: @digijay Obviously you're right. For the testing purposes I've used a .csv file which was not of my origin. Now, after your hint, I exported a new file from an excel sheet, with correct encoding, and, yap, it's working. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad I could help!